# Show values in another document controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show some JavaScript array values in another document Input Boxes. Previously, I was using:

```
document.getElementByID('....').value = ....
```

Now I want to know how to replace the 'document' with another page.

**Edited:**

My page opens two tables side-by-side. First table contains controls and the second contains and IFrame and inside that frame is enclosed a data-grid. When the user clicks on a row in the grid, results are fetched and I want to show in the controls of table1.

Comment: How do you mean 'another page'? A browser can only have one page loaded (except for iframes) in a window or tab, and cross window/tab communication isn't possible for good reasons

Comment: Clearing above. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the context of the jQuery method ie the `$(..., context)` to do this.

```
$("#someElement", top.document).val($("#someOtherElement").val());
```

This sets the value of `#someElement` in the main document, to the value of `#someOtherElement` in the iframe. Code is supposed to be run from within the iframe, because that's where your button handling is most likely to be.

To go the other way you could use:

```
$("#someElement", $("#iframeId").contents()).val($("#someOtherElement").val());
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript the only other `document`s you can reference are iframes inside the page itself that have the same domain. You could simply do, `var iframeDocument = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.document`